# Focus on multiple list view in one window form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, button, focus

I have a window form containing 2 list views (for instance, named a and b) and a button. The function of the button is supposedly to show a message box differently when there is focus between the 2 list views.

so the code for the button is

```
if (a.Focused)
   MessageBox.Show("a");
else
   MessageBox.Show("b");
```

However, when I selected the item in 'b' list view. It always return the MessageBox.Show(b). When I start over again and selected a item in 'a' list view, it give me an null reference exception.

Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: because when you click the button the focus shift on the button and both list view loose the focus. The null reference exception is a different story. to answer that you have not posted enough code. But Debugger is your best friend in such situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you click the button it's focused. So it will always show "b" because listview a is not focused.

Here's a suggestion: save the latest focused listview, and make a `GotFocus` event in both listviews (it's not in the designer so make it programatically), when clicking the button check what the latest focused listview is:

```
//Put this code after InitializeComponent();
ListViewA.GotFocus += ListViewFocus;
ListViewB.GotFocus += ListViewFocus;

...

private ListView Latest = null;
private void ListViewFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Latest = (sender as ListView);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Latest == null) MessageBox.Show("No listview is focused");
    else if (Latest.Name == "ListViewA") MessageBox.Show("a");
    else MessageBox.Show("b");
}
```

There's also a `LostFocus` event, if you want to make null again.

I don't know why you get the null reference exception. What line is causing it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for accepting my answer. It would be nice if you upvote too since it gives me more reputation :P